# sonarqube: quality profile used for the analysis of a specific snapshot

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to find out the quality profile used for the analysis of a specific snapshot?
It seems that during the lifetime of a project, different profiles have been used, and I am looking for a way to know which profile exactly was used on a per snapshot level.

Answer (score 0):

An event is logged each time the quality profile assigned to a project is changed. So you may find what you're looking for by browsing the events: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/History+and+Events#HistoryandEvents-Events